# SOAP Message Expiration

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-services, soap

How to use time-stamp in SOAP Header to implement Message Expiration?

Note: Using .NET 2.0, so ASMX Services and NO WCF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following links.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8728chd5%28VS.80%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77hkfhh8%28VS.71%29.aspx

If it helps please mark as answer.

Comment: Thanks Himadri. I saw this article earlier, went through this again. I can see few custom properties (Created & Expires) added to header and initialized before sending any request either way. But, I don't see any validation happening based on these properties or message getting expired.

Comment: Of course not. You have to do that yourself. SOAP has no concept of message expiration, so you have to add your own concept of message expiration.